# jQuery: looping continuous div carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a very simple carousel to cycle through a set of divs, I'm a bit stuck now though...in this case you can navigate from `slide 01` through to `slide 07` then back again, ideally I'd like the carousel to loop, thus after `slide 07` you get `slide 01`. The reason I'm not using a carousel plugin though (as you may suggest) is that I'd like an overhang, therefore when you're on `slide 01` you can see 50px of `slide 07` on the left and 50px of `slide 02` on the right.
See my jsFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/BBXnP/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="outerwrapper">
    <div class="innerwrapper">
        <div class="inner-slide">SLIDE 01</div>
        <div class="inner-slide">SLIDE 02</div>
        <div class="inner-slide">SLIDE 03</div>
        <div class="inner-slide">SLIDE 04</div>
        <div class="inner-slide">SLIDE 05</div>
        <div class="inner-slide">SLIDE 06</div>
        <div class="inner-slide">SLIDE 07</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="left">LEFT</div>
<div id="right">RIGHT</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {

    var animating = false,
        outerwrap = $(".outerwrapper");

    $("#right, #left").click(function () {
        if (animating) {
            return;
        }
        var dir = (this.id === "right") ? '+=' : '-=',
            width = $(".inner-slide").width();
        animating = true;
        outerwrap.animate({
            scrollLeft: dir + width
        }, 600, function () {
            animating = false;
        });
    });

});
```

FYI In the end it's going to work a little like the BBC homepage slider: http://www.bbc.co.uk where you can see the next and previous section underneath.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might be interested in the Mod operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by no means perfect, but it might give you a general idea of where to go. Also, I took the liberty of splitting up your code into sections a little bit.

The basic idea is to clone the first 2 and last 2 and put them at opposite ends of the list.

[Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmchk/)

Initialize variables:

```
var animating = false,
    slideWidth = $('.inner-slide').width(),
    $wrapper = $('.outerwrapper'),
    slideIndex = 2,
    slideLen = $('.inner-slide').length,
```

Build basic framework:

```
    build = function() {
        $firstClone = $('.inner-slide').eq(0).clone();
        $secondClone = $('.inner-slide').eq(1).clone();
        $preLastClone = $('.inner-slide').eq(slideLen - 2).clone();
        $lastClone = $('.inner-slide').eq(slideLen - 1).clone();
        $wrapper.find('.innerwrapper').append($firstClone, $secondClone).prepend($preLastClone, $lastClone);
        $wrapper.animate({
            scrollLeft: '+=' + slideWidth * slideIndex + 'px'
        }, 0);
    },
```

Function to slide wrapper

```
    slide = function(dir, speed) {
        if(!animating) {
            animating = true;
            dir == 'right' ? slideIndex++ : slideIndex--;
            slideIndex == slideLen - 1 ? slideIndex == 0 : '';

            if(slideIndex == 0 && dir == 'left') {
                //if the slide is at the beginning and going left

                slideIndex = slideLen + 1;                
                $wrapper.animate({
                    scrollLeft: slideIndex * slideWidth + 'px'
                }, 0, function() {
                    animating = false;    
                });
                slideIndex--;

            } else if(slideIndex == slideLen + 2 && dir == 'right') {
                //if the slide is at the end and going right

                slideIndex = 1;                
                $wrapper.animate({
                    scrollLeft: slideIndex * slideWidth + 'px'
                }, 0, function() {
                    animating = false;    
                });
                slideIndex++;

            }
            $wrapper.animate({
                scrollLeft: slideIndex * slideWidth + 'px'
            }, speed, function() {
                animating = false;    
            });
        }
    };
```

Actual execution:

```
$(function() {
    build();
    $('#right, #left').on('click', function() {
        slide($(this).attr('id'), 600)
    });
});
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do it, but this is a start!

Answer (score 1):

You propably know it, but take a look on .append() and .prepend() methods.

Code:

```
$('.innerwrapper').append($('.inner-slide').eq(0));
```

will move (not copy!) first slide to the last position in "innerwrapper" div and:

```
$('.innerwrapper').prepend($('.inner-slide').eq(-1));
```

will move last slide to the first position.

Cheers!